# How to register a Preview Handler for folders on Windows 10, version 1709?

Tags: c++, com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I recently observed that my preview handler for folders does not get instantiated on Windows 10, version 1709. This is surprising because the handler works perfectly on systems running from Windows 7 up to Windows 10, version 1607.

The preview handler is registered in the [standarized way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144144(v=vs.85).aspx) under *ProgID* `Directory`:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    Directory
        shellex
            {8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}
                (Default) = [REG_SZ] {1F176730-9812-47D8-8163-35D7C1CA0FBF}
```

The differences between a working and a non-working system can be tracked down by monitoring the registry access of Windows Explorer. When a preview of a folder should be requested on a 1607 system, Process Monitor produces the expected output:

[image]

On the other hand, on a 1709 system there is no registry access below the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory` key at all. That's why I suspect that the different behaviour (unfortunately) does not have anything to do with my handler code and that the preview handler support for folders may has been removed in recent Windows versions.

I also tested using *ProgID* `Folder` instead of `Directory` without success and verified that my preview handler gets instantiated generally, at least on files, by registering the handler at `AllFileSystemObjects`.

Has anybody experience with running preview handlers for folders on latest Windows versions?

Comment: Have you looked at the event log to see if anything shows up? Perhaps MS switched to requiring that DLs housing COM objects instantiated by the shell be signed (that's a pure guess btw), but something nay well show up in the log.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: There is nothing suspicious in the event log. I think, the explorer does not even come to the point where to check the DLLs for a signature, because the explorer would have to determine by accessing the registry which DLL is registered as a preview handler. Simply, this registry access is missing completely. On the other hand, registering my preview handler for files works without problem. Thanks for your advice.